# insert ajax using unsuccessfully

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I searched a lot how to insert ajax to my form, but so far unsuccessfully, I attached my code if anyone can see where is the problem and have any idea how to solve it. thanks!

html will be like:

> ```
> <div id="error">
>                 <?php $error; ?>
>   </div>
>             <input name="uname" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="insert"/>
>             <input name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="insert"/>
> ```

jquery will be like:

```
$.post('/reg.php',
            {
               uname: $('.input').val(),
               fname: $('.input').val();

            function(response) {
                // update your div with errors
                $('#error').html(response);
            })
```

Comment: Error in the line : `  uname: $('.input').val(), fname: $('.input').val();` you shouls write clas name there as `.` is for class ans `#` for id

Comment: please check my answer. I hope it solves your issue, which I've mentioned my comments

Answer (score 0):

there are few mistakes in your script. you cant access like $('.input').val(). Try:

```
<input name="uname" id="uname" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="insert"/>
<input name="fname" id="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="insert"/>


$.post( '/reg.php', { uname: $('#uname').val(), fname: $('#fname').val() })
  .done(function( response ) {
    $('#error').html(response);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code :

```
$.post('/reg.php',
{
    uname: $('.uname').val(), // by class 
    fname: $('.fname').val();  // by class

    // or uname: $('#uname').val() // by id
    // or fname: $('.fname').val() // by id

    function(response) {
       // update your div with errors
      $('#error').html(response);
})
```

And also your HTML:

```
<div id="error"></div>
<input name="uname" id="uname" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="uname"/>
<input name="fname" id="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="fname"/>
```

Comment: I added an id for each like you suggested but it still not working

Comment: @AriEfron, did you changed class and tried my complete code as I mentioned

Comment: yes I did, maybe the issue is this:  <div id="error">
                <?php echo reg::$error ; ?>
                </div>

Comment: @AriEfron ,I didn't used `<?php echo reg::$error ; ?>` in my code, also you need to add `.done(function(response))` done before function response, else your function won't be called